# user input as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a small function in javascript to get user input from a text input form to be used as the delay time for fading away but it fails please help

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="new" placeholder="Fade Duration(milliseconds)"/>

var x = document.getElementById("new").value;
$(".fadeInbox").click(function () {
    $("#section1").delay(x).fadeIn();
    $("#section2").delay(x).fadeIn();
});



$(".fadeOutbox").click(function () {
    $("#section1").delay(x).fadeOut();
    $("#section2").delay(x).fadeOut();

});
```

Comment: change `var x = document.getElementById("new").value;` to `var x = Number(document.getElementById("new").value);`

Comment: The `value` property of an [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) returns a string

Comment: thanks i will try that

Comment: if you are using jQuery, it would be easier to get the value with `var x = $("#new").val();`, writing much less

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Comment: yes thank you. Your answer below works fine

Answer (score 1):

`var x` from `input` is a `string` not a `int`, so

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("new").value);
...
```

or

```
var x = +document.getElementById("new").value;
...
```

Comment: i moved var x = `document.getElementById("new").value;` into the two functions and solved my problem

Comment: Even then you should make them `int`

Comment: will definately do that

Answer (score 0):

You should put the

```
var x = document.getElementById("new").value;
```

inside the functions, or it will be executed only once immediately after the script loads (and not work).

Answer (score 0):

The delay should be checked inside the functions, otherwise the value will be checked only once - when the page loads. If it's inside the functions it will be checked every time the function is triggered.

```
$(".fadeInbox").click(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("new").value;
    $("#section1").delay(x).fadeIn();
    $("#section2").delay(x).fadeIn();
});

$(".fadeOutbox").click(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("new").value;
    $("#section1").delay(x).fadeOut();
    $("#section2").delay(x).fadeOut();
});
```